# Sybase test data generation - Dates

Tags: database, sybase, test-data, powerdesigner

When I create test data in PowerDesigner 16.1, the software always includes a time right next to the date.

Is there any way to modify the test data generation to remove the time and only get the dates, following this format (mm/dd/yyyy)?

When I generate test data, I get something like this:

```
INSERT INTO test ('a', 'b', '2020-5-7 0:0:0')
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: For which DBMS are you generating? I picked Sybase ASE 15.5 as an example, and the generated data depends on the column data type: with columns defined as datetime, date, time, I got lines like `insert into TABLE_1 (COLUMN_1, COLUMN_2, COLUMN_3) values ('2004-9-10 4:26:24', '2006-7-26', '4:35:37')`.

Comment: with ASE you can insert (just) a date into a `datetime` column and ASE will default the time component to `12:00:00 AM`; but I agree with Mitch ... if you don't need the time component then use the `date` datatype to eliminate the extra space needed to store the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. When I create the CDM, I set my date column to 'Date' datatype.

When I pass to the LDM, I need to set again all the dates columns to 'Date' datatype, because the software changes automatically to 'DateTime' datatype.

And finally, when I construct the PDM, I must change again all the dates columns to 'Date' datatype, because the software for some reason, automatically changes it to 'DateTime' datatype  again.

Comment: Use a PDM Domain to give the type of your columns. So that you have only one type to change.